# How to write a submenu with vuejs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

There is a `Select` of vue-strap:http://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/#select
[image]

I want a submenu with vuejs,like this:
When clicking one item of `Select` of vue-strap,it will show a submenu,then,
clicking one item of submenu,the value will be shown behind `Select data :`, as shown in the image above.

I have no idea how to write it,any ideas or a demo?

Comment: If you are okay with using a Bootstrap dropdown list with multiple list levels I've got a quick and rough example here: https://jsfiddle.net/jimutt/kd64shwj/

If you think my solution is enough I'll go ahead and post it as an answer. 

It's perhaps not really a straight answer to your question but it's at least a possible way of implementing the kind of functionality you're looking for which could easily be implemented in a more stand-alone component later.

Comment: @jimutt Thanks very much.I am looking forward to your answer.